# Web service API SOAP v1 using java for connect?

Tags: javascript, soap-api-v2, web-services

In official site exists this faq
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html
And in line `As of v1.3, you may also use the following URL to access the Magento API v2, which has been added to improve compatibility with Java and .NET:` 
He says that in v2 java is more compatible. I researched and found that there are some ways to connect to java ws magento.

**the first:** https://github.com/webdevwilson/magento-java

**the second:** http://code.google.com/p/magja/

Which one do you recommend? Which is easier to implement? why did some tests and got no satisfactory result

I want to know if I can also use the V1 magento ws to connect USING only java